# Too many empty prompt lines when repeating the last command in GDB in Emacs

Tags: gdb

GDB has a feature: when the user wants to repeat the previous command (for example "n"), she can simply hit Enter.

When using GDB with a source code viewer in a terminal (`gdb -tui`), repeat the last command simply does not create new command prompt lines and preserves what is currently displayed on the screen. However, when doing this in Emacs, this will create a lot of empty command prompt lines.

How can I make Emacs not create new lines when repeating the previous GDB command?